# Pytorch variable changes numpy variable even though memory addresses are not same

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have the following bit of code:

```
a = torch.ones(10); b = a.numpy()
a[0] += 1
print(a, b)
```

Both variables essentially hold the same values even though I only modified `a`. However, I checked the memory addresses of `a` and `b` using `hex(id(a))` and they're different. So in this case, is `b` a pointer to `a`? What's going on?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about `torch`, but with `numpy` it is possible to have two arrays (with different `id`), that share a data buffer.  The second is often described as being a `view` of the first.

Comment: Well, comparing tensor with ndarray raises TypeError here. How could it reurn True?

Comment: @zihaozhihao I've editted the post.

Comment: The raw data is actually at the same address. id method is returning the entire obj address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the raw data is at the same address. You can check like this,

```
a.storage().data_ptr()
```

Out[16]: 93866530123392

```
b.__array_interface__['data']
```

Out[17]: (93866530123392, False)

Comment: So what exactly does this mean? When we do `b = a.numpy()`, is that just a pointer?

Comment: @Jonathan, this answer is the exact explanation.  Thinking about it as a 'pointer' might help you, but it isn't the exact meaning.  `b` is a numpy array object, that has, as one its attributes, a reference to the same data buffer (C array) the `torch` storage.